# Spin Correlation Analogy in Three Particle System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I have recently gone through the section on Bell's Inequality in "Modern Quantum Mechanics" by J.J. Sakurai and Jim Napolitano and I am curious as to weather or not there are analogous situations for systems of more than two particles. Are there any known physical mechanisms so as to decompose a system with a total spin of 1/2 into a system of three entangled 1/2 spin particles, (therein occupying the s = m = 1/2 state), so that at least one particle may be significantly separated from the others? If not, are there any similar mechanisms for higher amounts of particles in general?

Comment: Not sure this qualifies as an answer, as I don't know about getting specifically 3 entangled spin 1/2 particles.  But switching over to photons (which are used for most Bell tests and their variants), there is much to discuss.  There is no particular limit to the number that can be entangled (and that applies to any system of quantum particles). 3 and 4 photons are regularly generated into entangled states, some of which are maximally entangled.  The best known are GHZ states, and the GHZ theorem is an analog to Bell in that it presents a strong contradiction between QM and Local Realism.

Comment: @DrChinese Thank you for your insight. If you wouldn't mind a small additional question: in such a state (a three particle entangled state), is it possible to unentangle only ONE of the particles, so as to leave the other two entangled?

Comment: The answer depends.  For 3 photon GHZ states, there is generally no remaining entanglement after measurement of any of the 3 - but there are some exceptions. The initial state is |000>+|111>. Another 3 photon state is called the W state, which is initially |100>+|010>+|001>. A measurement on any 1 leaves the other 2 entangled, although there is no way to know if it is in the |01> or |10> state. A simple intro to GHZ is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state but a better treatment by Zeilinger is https://www.drchinese.com/David/Bell-MultiPhotonGHZ.pdf